# ngModel undefined when using directive - Angularjs controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

My ngModel is undefined when using the ngPattern directive. If I remove ngPattern, the ngModel works as expected. See [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/l9MnItTfUgFD4d5Kwp5P?p=preview).

Note how vm.condition does not show when typing a value in the text box, but as soon as the ngPattern is removed, vm.condition shows as expected.

HTML

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm">
    <div ng-form="vm.frmTest">
      <input id="txtHealth" name="txtHealth" type="text" ng-model="vm.condition" ng-pattern="/^(.+)$/g">
      <div class="help-block" ng-messages="vm.frmTest.txtHealth.$error" ng-show="vm.frmTest.txtHealth.$invalid">
        <p ng-message="pattern">Error.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <span>{{vm.condition}}</span>
</body>
```

JS

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    this.condition = '';
});
```

NOTE: This is a dumbed down version showing the issue. My directive is showing the same issue.

Comment: You should use just `pattern` in this case

Comment: does my answer help your need??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably because of the pattern string that you are using in your directive. Try having a `$scope` bind and check your directive. You can check the relative **PLUNKER** example here:

[Demo Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/2KJlpgn3yVMhMSatTOTK?p=preview)

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular-messages.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm">
    <div ng-form="vm.frmTest">
      <input id="txtHealth" name="txtHealth" type="text" ng-model="vm.condition" ng-pattern="re">
      <div class="help-block" ng-messages="vm.frmTest.txtHealth.$error" ng-show="vm.frmTest.txtHealth.$invalid">
        <p ng-message="pattern">Error.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <span>{{vm.condition}}</span>
  </body>

</html>
```

**JS:**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  this.condition = '';
  $scope.re = /^(.+)$/g;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use vm on the view then you will need to declare vm on your controller.

```
var vm = this;
```